# What is the equivalent of this UPDATE SQL query in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

```
 UPDATE tblNames 
 SET tblNames.firstName = John 
 WHERE tblNames.ID = 1
```

Comment: You can read tutorial about entity framework from here: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it as below:

```
using (var context = new DBEntities())
{
    var entity = context.tblNames.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == 1); 
    entity.firstName = "John";
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: C# is **sensitive** to upper/lowercase - the spelling **is crucial** - use the proper `.FirstOrDefault()` - **not** `.firstordefault()` .....

Comment: Thanks Mate! it works! :)